# How to write `new object[] {}` in F#?

Tags: f#

I need to convert the following C# code to F#. How to convert `new object[] {}` in the following code?

```
var table = (Hashtable) cookies.GetType().InvokeMember("m_domainTable",
                                                       BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                       BindingFlags.GetField |
                                                       BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                       null,
                                                       cookies,
                                                       new object[] { });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[||]` if type inference doesn't infer it properly you can always annotate the type:

```
    ... ,null ,cookies, [||] : obj [])
```

But in that specific case the type annotation will not be needed since there are no conflicting overloads:

```
let table =  
    cookies.GetType()
        .InvokeMember("m_domainTable",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic |||
            BindingFlags.GetField  |||
            BindingFlags.Instance,
            null,
            cookies,
            [||]) :?> Hashtable
```

Comment: It's worth noting that F# doesn't have anonymous objects.

Comment: [`Array.empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353904.aspx) could also be used (and reads nicely).